# Creating a Menu of Items via ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist, menu

so what I'm trying to do is create a menu of food items with ArrayLists.  My task is to complete the following definition of the static method profits that inputs an ArrayList items of MenuItems and returns an array of doubles. Each entry in the output is the difference between the price and the cost of the corresponding element of items. I have to process the result of each calculation involving money using the static method roundMoney.

```
    public class MenuItem 
    { 
      private String myName; 

      private double myPrice, 
                     myCost; 

      private int    myCode; 

      private boolean myAvailability; 

      public MenuItem( String name, double price, double cost, int code, boolean available ) 
      { 
        myName = name; 
        myPrice = price; 
        myCost = cost; 
        myCode = code; 
        myAvailability = available; 
      } 

      public String getName() { return myName; } 
      public double getPrice() { return myPrice; } 
      public double getCost() { return myCost; } 
      public int getCode() { return myCode; } 
      public boolean available() { return myAvailability; } 


      public String menuString() 
        { 
            return getName() + " ($" + getPrice() + ")"; 
        } 


      public static double roundMoney( double amount ) 
      { 
        return (int)(100 * amount + 0.5) / 100.0; 
      } 

      public static String printAmount( double d ) 
      { 
        String s = "" + d; 
        int k = s.indexOf( "." ); 
        if ( k < 0 ) 
          return s + ".00"; 
        if ( k + 1 == s.length() ) 
          return s + "00"; 
        if ( k + 2 == s.length() ) 
          return s + "0"; 
        else 
          return s; 
      } 
    } 
       //***********************************************************************
    public static double[] Profits(ArrayList<MenuItem> items) 
    {
        double[] profits = new double[items.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < profits.length; i++)
         {
            profits[i] = roundMoney (items.get(i).getPrice() - items.get(i).getCost()); 
         }
        return profits;
    }
     //***********************************************************************
public static void main( String[] args )
{  
    ArrayList<MenuItem> items1 = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
    items1.add( new MenuItem("Stir Fry",5.43,0.45,1,true) );
    items1.add( new MenuItem("Nachos",3.49,0.15,0,false) );
    items1.add( new MenuItem("Mud Pie",6.50,1.25,2,true) );
    items1.add( new MenuItem("Jerk Chicken",8.99,3.20,1,false) );

    double[] t = profits( items1 );

    for ( double d : t )
      System.out.print( printAmount( d ) + " " );
}
```

My expected result is: 4.98 3.34 5.25 5.79, but I keep receiving the error: TC1.java:30: error: cannot find symbol

double[] t = profits( items1 ); 
Could somebody please help me figure out what's wrong?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define your function `profits` with a capital "P."

```
public static double[] Profits(ArrayList<MenuItem> items)
```

Change the line with the error to match the name of the function:

```
double[] t = Profits( items1 );
```

Comment: or (better) make it (as well as any other method names) low case

Comment: Thank you.  Excuse me, I need to go slam my head into a door.

Comment: It is not always the best choice to rename functions.  Lower case function names are not always a standard and renaming a function can cause more errors else where in code.  I typically find it better to address the error first, and then see about refactoring.

Comment: I understand, but it's not a big deal in this case because the main method is already provided, so I only needed to write what was prior to that.  It was just my clumsiness.

Comment: your welcome!  Note that @PM77-1 mentioned refactoring your function name to start with a lower case "p".  Common java coding convention uses an upper case leading character for classes, and lower case for functions.

Answer (score -1):

There is a sytanx issue for the MenuItem.java
Try running the below program.

---

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MenuItem 
{ 
  private String myName; 

  private double myPrice, 
                 myCost; 

  private int    myCode; 

  private boolean myAvailability; 

  public MenuItem( String name, double price, double cost, int code, boolean available ) 
  { 
    myName = name; 
    myPrice = price; 
    myCost = cost; 
    myCode = code; 
    myAvailability = available; 
  } 

  public String getName() { return myName; } 
  public double getPrice() { return myPrice; } 
  public double getCost() { return myCost; } 
  public int getCode() { return myCode; } 
  public boolean available() { return myAvailability; } 


  public String menuString() 
    { 
        return getName() + " ($" + getPrice() + ")"; 
    } 


  public static double roundMoney( double amount ) 
  { 
    return (int)(100 * amount + 0.5) / 100.0; 
  } 

  public static String printAmount( double d ) 
  { 
    String s = "" + d; 
    int k = s.indexOf( "." ); 
    if ( k < 0 ) 
      return s + ".00"; 
    if ( k + 1 == s.length() ) 
      return s + "00"; 
    if ( k + 2 == s.length() ) 
      return s + "0"; 
    else 
      return s; 
  } 

   //***********************************************************************
public static double[] profits(ArrayList<MenuItem> items) 
{
    double[] profits = new double[items.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < profits.length; i++)
     {
        profits[i] = roundMoney (items.get(i).getPrice() - items.get(i).getCost()); 
     }
    return profits;
}
 //***********************************************************************
public static void main( String[] args )
{  
ArrayList<MenuItem> items1 = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
items1.add( new MenuItem("Stir Fry",5.43,0.45,1,true) );
items1.add( new MenuItem("Nachos",3.49,0.15,0,false) );
items1.add( new MenuItem("Mud Pie",6.50,1.25,2,true) );
items1.add( new MenuItem("Jerk Chicken",8.99,3.20,1,false) );

double[] t = profits( items1 );

for ( double d : t )
  System.out.print( printAmount( d ) + " " );
}
}
```